# How could i send a file in compact framework?

Tags: sockets, compact-framework, windows-ce, send

i have found an instruction to send a file (xml in my case) to my device: [Socket.SendFile(myXml)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.ipaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) My problem is sendFile() does not exist in compact framework. 
So how could i send a file with compact framework on the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a combination of [Socket.Send()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145160%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [Filestream.Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for that.

Just read N bytes from the file and then write N bytes to your socket until you've covered the entire file. The second link has an example for reading files. Replace the section labeled "// Write the byte array to the other FileStream." with your Socket.Send() calls.